# Java: Methods with loops

Tags: math

Define the method `outputValue()` that takes two integer parameters and outputs the product of all negative integers starting with the first and ending with the second parameter. If no negative integers exist, product is 1. End with a newline. The method does not return any value.

Ex: If the input is `-4 7`, then the output is, `24`

I only need help understanding the math going on in this question. I don't get how `-4` and `7` outputs `24`. Am I supposed to multiply? Add? Subtract? That' s all the explanation that I need.
Another example is:
If the input is `-7 1`, then the output is: `-28`.
Thanks!

Comment: "first and ending with the second parameter" -> `-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` ! "all negative integers" -> `-4, -3, -2, -1` ! "product of all negative integers" -> `-4 * -3 * -2 * -1` ((product == multiplication)) And this question is not related to the Java Programming Language! Or loops! Or Programming!

Comment: Are you aware of the relation of "product of two integers" and "multiply two integers"? I suspect that you read "product" as "result", but it also has the meaning in math of "the result of multiplication".

Comment: @user16320675 Would you mind me quoting most of your comment in my answer? Maybe you are creating your own answer?

Comment: @Yunnosch go for it, I don't mind at all, I'm not writing any answer (if possible) BTW my comments tend to get deleted after some time..., better quote the content, not just refer to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are supposed to multiply.
I consider this the answer to the question, based on the assumption that you read the word "product" as "result" and missed the more specific meaning from math as "the result of multiplication".

You also state "I don't get how -4 and 7 outputs 24", I assume that is because you lack the multiplication detail. But in case you also missed the implication of a range allow me to refer to the first part of the comment by user16320675.

> "starting with thefirst and ending with the second parameter" -> -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ! "all negative integers" -> -4, -3, -2, -1 ! "product of all negative integers" -> -4 * -3 * -2 * -1

(I extended the quote at the start with more quote from your question. They also briefly point out product==multiplication. I think the misunderstanding or missed detail needs more highlighting, that is why I put this answer together to help you. Still, the credit for the range explanation is theirs.)

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. I was in fact reading it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The "product" implies multiplication.  So how many negative integers are between -4 and 7 including -4 but excluding 7.  That would be -4,-3,-2,-1.  The product of those 12 * 2 = 24.

```
outputValue(-4, 7);
outputValue(-1,8);
outputValue(-10, -1);
outputValue(0,10);
```

prints

```
24
-1
-3628800
1
```

```
public static void outputValue(int a, int b) {
   b = b > -1 ? 0 : b; // if b is >= 0, then just loop to 0.
                       // if a >= 0, the loop won't run and 1 will be 
                       // printed.
   int  product = 1;
   for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
       product *= i;
   }
   System.out.println(product);
}
```